# Class loaded with ClassLoader but fails when instantiated due to referenced class

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I'm loading a class from an external jar like this:

```
private Class<?> loadClassFromJar(File jarFile, String className) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        URL jarUrl = jarFile.toURI().toURL();
        try (URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL(jarUrl)}, this.getClass().getClassLoader())) {
            return Class.forName(className, true, ucl);
}
```

The class I'm loading (class A) uses class B as instance variable `private final B b`. This variable is instantiated in the constructor.
As I mentioned in the title, class A gets loaded without problems - the method `loadClassFromJar()` works fine.
But, when I try to instantiate class A, I get `ClassNotFoundException` for class B.
This is how I instantiate the class A:

```
Constructor<?> constructor = loadClassFromJar(jarFile, className).getConstructor(argsClasses);
constructor.newInstance(argsInstances);
```

I have a unit test covering this. When I run it, this is the exception I get:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.foo.bar.Main.getDatasetConverterFromJar(Main.java:197)
at com.foo.bar.Main.MainTest.lambda$testConfig$0(MainTest.java:58)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
at com.foo.bar.MainTest.testConfig(MainTest.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.foo.bar.Main.getDatasetConverterFromJar(Main.java:185)
... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.x.y.B
at com.x.y.A.<init>(A.java:53)
at com.x.y.A.<init>(A.java:47)
... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.x.y.B
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
... 81 more
```

Interesting observations:

- I wanted to see some information about the loaded class and as I was putting a bunch of logs in `loadClassFromJar()` I noticed that calling
  `System.out.println(aClass.getClasses()))` after `Class.forName()` call fixes the issue - no Exception is thrown. Of course, this doesn't explain what actually happens and is not a viable solution.
- Loading class B explicitly with `ucl.loadClass("B")` before loading class A fixes the issue.
- I also tried putting class B in class A as a public static inner class, thinking that both of them might get loaded properly, but this didn't work - I got the same exception as in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the `URLClassLoader` too early.

#### What closing a `URLClassLoader` means

If you view the [Javadoc of `URLClassLoader#close`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#close()), you can see the following:

> Closes this URLClassLoader, so that it can no longer be used to load new classes or resources that are defined by this loader. Classes and resources defined by any of this loader's parents in the delegation hierarchy are still accessible. Also, any classes or resources that are already loaded, are still accessible.

So, it cannot load any new classes after you closed it.

#### Why it fails

In your case, you are using the `URLClassLoader` in a try-with-resources block.
In that, you are loading class `A` with `Class.forName` which works perfectly fine.

However, because of the try-with-resources, the `URLClassLoader` is closed after the class is loaded.

When using it, it needs to access another class, `B`.
It tries to load that class automatically which fails resulting in the exception.

#### How to fix it

So, you should *not* close the `URLClassLoader` before all of the code from that is finished. But you should close it as soon as you don't need it any more (when you don't need the code from that `URLClassLoader`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This explains and fixes the issue.